# Detect specific number using regexp

Tags: regex, string, matlab

Any ideas how to detect the 3 in (>3<)and not 3 in (rank_value_3_months)?

```
"<span data-bind-domain="rank_value_3_months">3</span>" 



rank(i) = str2double(regexp(CharData7,'>(\d)<','match','once'))
```

[image]

Here is my whole code for this part, I would like to detect the number inside (>number<) after the pre-prosses file,

```
%function [feature7] = f7(data)

for i = 1:1

%start read html file
data2=fopen(strcat('DATA\WHOIS\TR\',int2str(i),'.htm'),'r')
CharData = fread(data2, '*char')';  %read text file and store data in CharData
fclose(data2);
%end read html file

register_date = regexp(CharData, '<span data-bind-   domain="rank_value_3_months">.*?/span>', 'match'); %checking

%start write only http in image file
fid = fopen(strcat('DATA\PRE-PROCESS_DATA\F23_TR\f23_TR_pdata_',int2str(i)),'w');
for col = 1:numel(register_date)
 fprintf(fid,'%s\n',register_date{:,col});
end
fclose(fid);
%end write only http in image file

s = dir(strcat('DATA\PRE-PROCESS_DATA\F23_TR\','f23_TR_pdata_', int2str(i)));
disp(s.bytes); 

if s.bytes ~= 0

   data7=fopen(strcat('DATA\PRE-PROCESS_DATA\F23_TR\f23_TR_pdata_',int2str(i),''),'r')

   CharData7 = fread(data7, '*char')';  %read text file and store data in CharData
   fclose(data7);

  rank(i) = str2double(regexp(CharData7,'>(\d)<','tokens','once') )

  else

  end

  if rank(i)~=0
   feature23(i)=-1;
  else
   feature23(i)=1;
  end
  end
```

Comment: Your `regexp(CharData7,'>(\d)<','match','once')` already returns `'>3<'`. What's the question?

Comment: but i get the output as " nan nan nan ..."
i could not get the correct output like (3), I want the output return me rank =[3]

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `CharData7` is a cell array, you can try this:

```
%// The find 
%// - use 'tokens' to return just the part in brackets
%// - use \s* to make spacing flexible (which is also valid XML/HTML)
rank = regexp(CharData7, '>\s*(\d)\s*<', 'tokens', 'once');

%// Re-format into flat cells 
%// ('tokens' returns ALL tokens, which is therefore a cell, regardless
%// of the 'once' setting)
rank = [rank{:}];

%// and convert everything to double
rank(i) = str2double(rank)
```

So, in a nice illegible one-liner:

```
rank(i) = str2double([builtin('_brace', regexp(C,'>\s*(\d)\s*<','tokens','once'), :)]);
```

In case `CharData7` is just a single string, you can skip the cell-flattening step:

```
 rank(i) = str2double( regexp(C,'>\s*(\d)\s*<','tokens','once') )
```

Comment: @user3340270: In my tests this came out correct, so you have something else in your code that's messing things up. Could you post a minimal example of the string and loop you use that I can use to reproduce the problem?

Comment: @user3340270: Also, what's your MATLAB version?

Comment: hi @Rody, I have posted d part of my problem as above, i used matlab version: MATLAB 7.7.0(R2008b)

Comment: @user3340270: Thank you. Can you also post an example of the HTM files you're reading?

Comment: my .htm/code file is too long, but i save from this link (http://who.is/whois/google.com.my). this is the page i saved down.

Comment: i want to detect the Alexa Trend/Rank Three Month :399, so that my output is rank=[399]

Comment: @user3340270: I see no problem (I get 399)...I'm on R2010a, and I see nothing that should be version dependent...Only thin I corrected was an empty `register_date` in the code you posted, which was because of an incorrect match string...My advice is to just print the outputs of all relevant lines to the MATLAB command prompt and/or use the debugger with breakpoints, to find out what's going on.